# Is it possible to sum distinct rows without a sub select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the total number of package items & package items that are outstanding, for a given responsible party and set of packages.

The table I have to report from is semi rolled up at the package level and repeats the data I need.
This means a simple sum will not work.

I can work around this by doing a distinct select and then selecting the sums from this.

My question is:
Is it possible to do the same query with out using a sub select?
Is there any point to solving it without using a sub select?

Here is an example of the query:

```
SELECT
    Sum(Outstanding) as Outstanding,
    Sum(Total) as Total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        O as Outstanding,
        T as Total
    FROM
        PackageTotals
    WHERE
        Package in ('XYZ', 'ABC', 'LMN')
        AND Responsible = 'ZZ'
) Data
```

Comment: Why would there be duplicate rows on the packagetotals table? Are you sure the values in every column are the same? Can you provide  a list of all the columns on that table and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference between your query and doing this:

```
Select 
  sum(distinct outstanding) as outstanding,
  Sum(distinct total) as total
From
 packagetotals
Where
  package in ('xyz', 'ABC',  'LMN')
  And responsible = 'zz'
```

However this could be indicative of a larger data problem

I think the only difference you'll find here is readability.  I would prefer mine in readability, but for performance the difference will I'm sure be negligible.

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a48d/1)

Comment: I agree, the data is a bit funky. However it comes from a system I can't control, I just have to report out of it.